# PCRE and Whitespace

Tags: c, pcre

Using PCRE lib...wanting to look for a string of words up to a known number of whitespace.

i.e.  5 white space characters between tokens.

foo bar foo bar foo bar = between the first foo and last bar....there are 5 space.

foo     bar = this also has 5 spaces between the first foo and last bar.

Anyone have the regular expression to find both of these....and variations of spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the second example, I only see 1 whitespace between foo and bar.

Comment: The second example, 'foo    bar' has become 'foo bar'.  I couldn't edit it.  You got to format it properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\S*(\s\S*){N}
```

where *N* is the number of whitespace characters you want. Note, also matches a string of *N* whitespace characters without anything in between them.